# Have you found a universal solution to the `filesystem:` URL scheme?

Tags: javascript, filesystems, w3c, html5-filesystem

In [article](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/07/why-no-filesystem-api-in-firefox/) about FileSystem API on hacks.mozilla.com it is writen:

> There is one more capability that exist in the FileSystem API not
>   covered above. The specification introduces a new filesystem: URL
>   scheme. When loading URLs from filesystem: it returns the contents of
>   files in stored using the FileSystem API. This is a very cool feature
>   for a couple of reasons. First of all these URLs are predictable. Once
>   you’ve stored a file in the file system, you always know which URL can
>   be used to load from it. And the URL will continue to work as long as
>   the file is stored in the file system, even if the web page is
>   reloaded. Second, relative URLs work with the filesystem: scheme. So
>   you can create links from one resource stored in the filesystem to
>   another resource stored in the filesystem.
>
> Firefox does support the blob: URL scheme, which does allow loading
>   data from a Blob anywhere where URLs can be used. However it doesn’t
>   have the above mentioned capabilities. This is something that I’d
>   really like to find a solution for. If we can’t find a better
>   solution, implementing the Google specifications is definitely an
>   option.

Have you found a universal solution to the `filesystem:` URL scheme?

Answer (score 1):

That article is from 2012. The URL scheme discussed was abandoned by the W3C, and IANA, which controls URL schemes. See [the document  at IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/historic/filesystem).

Comment: What will replace it? Jonas Sicking wrote there that want something to replace it with.

Comment: Sounds like a question for Jonas Sicking. The question was whether there was a solution for the `filesystem:`URL scheme. The answer is above. There's [the `blob:` scheme](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#url), but I believe its purpose is not the same.

Comment: This question is for all who know the answer. ;)